# Почему the_post() не отображает пост?

Tags: php, wordpress

Переходя на ссылку поста не получается получить пост из the_post код следующий

```
<?php if(have_posts()) {?>
     <?php the_post(); ?>
<?php }?>
```

При это have_posts возвращает 1. Пробывал WP_Query($args) результат тот же самый

Comment: читайте что делает [the_post()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_post)

Answer (score 1):

Функция `the_post()` ничего не выводит сама по себе и ничего не возвращает. Грубо говоря, она просто устанавливает глобальную переменную `$post`, чтобы другие функции знали, какой именно пост считается активным в данный момент в общем цикле (Loop).

Насколько я понял, вас интересуют скорее функции вывода: `the_title()`, `the_content()`, `the_category()`. Первая выводит заголовок активного поста, вторая — его содержимое, третья — список рубрик.

Важно понимать, что ваш пост выводится не сам по себе, а внутри цикла (Loop). Даже когда вы находитесь на внутренней странице отдельного поста, вы всё равно проходите через цикл (просто в нём будет один элемент — текущий пост).

Вот как это работает:

```
<?php 

// Проверяем, есть ли вообще какие-нибудь посты в главной выборке (main query)
if ( have_posts() ): 

    // Обрабатываем по очереди каждый пост из выборки, пока не обойдём все
    // (всегда в цикле, потому что выборка может вызываться с доп. параметрами и содержать несколько объектов, а не один)
    while ( have_posts() ):

         // Сообщаем системе, что текущий пост — активный
         // и что в этом проходе по циклу все данные нужно брать именно из него
         the_post();

         // А вот теперь можно начинать выводить данные
         // с помощью стандартных «циклических» функций 
         // (которые и предназначены только для работы внутри цикла)

         // Выводим заголовок *активного* поста
         the_title();

         // Выводим контент *активного* поста
         the_content();

         // Выводим список рубрик *активного* поста
         the_category();

    endwhile; 

endif; 
?>
```